# Can I type hint a subset of a Union in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

### Usecase

I'd like a heterogenous queue to which producers can register at runtime.
This would be for use in an Elm-style tui system.
Thus, libraries could provide various registration functions for users, for hhtp requests etc.
The question is, what should the signature of those functions be?

I want the user to be able to declare to the type system what kind of events they'd like to handle: `Queue[Union[...]]`, but also registration functions to accept `any queue which has T as a Union member`. Is that possible to express?

### Full example

```py
from queue import Queue
from typing import Union


def register_str_source(queue: "Queue[str]"): ...
def register_int_source(queue: "Queue[int]"): ...


queue: "Queue[Union[str, int]]" = Queue()

# Argument 1 to "register_str_source" has incompatible type "Queue[Union[str, int]]"; expected "Queue[str]"
register_str_source(queue)

# Argument 1 to "register_int_source" has incompatible type "Queue[Union[str, int]]"; expected "Queue[int]"
register_int_source(queue)

while event := queue.get(): # Exhaustive types are desirable here
    if isinstance(event, str):
        print(event)  # One may choose to register to additional events when handling this one
    elif isinstance(event, int):
        print(event)
```

### Notes

I've tried:

- `Union[str, ...]`. This is invalid
- Using a bare `Queue` in the `register_*` functions. This doesn't catch a `Queue.put` of the wrong type within that scope.
- Could there be a use for `TypeVar`s and `Protocol`s here?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using a contravariant generic class that wraps Queue.

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types